# Execute John the Ripper on multiple processors using mpirun

Tags: permissions, sudo, mpi

I am trying to optimize John the Ripper for a security class. I am trying to use both processors to run John by using the `mpirun` program as suggested in [this tutorial](http://easymactips.blogspot.com/2012/09/john-ripper-tutorial-examples-and.html). I installed `mpirun`, but when I run this command, I get the following error:

```
# sudo mpirun -np2 /usr/share/john --test=10 
/usr/bin/mpirun: 1: eval: usr/share/john: Permission denied.
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I run John with two processors using `mpirun`? I am running Ubuntu 12.10 on a VMware Fusion machine on a Mac with an Intel Core i5

Comment: You can also compile John with OpenMP, which speeds up certain hash types. The jumbo patch includes OpenMP support and many more optimizations and hash types: https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/share/john` is probably not the path to the binary, but to the
folder containing application specific data.

Try

```
sudo mpirun -np 2 /usr/sbin/john --test=10
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks. When I ran that command I got an error saying john.ini is missing. I copied the john.ini file. Now when I run the command that you suggest from root, I get: Unrecognized argument -np2 ignored. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is a space missing after `-np`. I updated my answer.

Comment: And you can call `john` as normal user, you do not need sudo.